# WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

In my Spring Application i'm doing like this..

My Jsp form click hyper link form will be sent..

```
<form:form action="user" modelAttribute="NAME">

   <a href="href_form1" onclick="onClick_Save()" class="save">Save</a>

</fomr:form>
<script>
  function onClick_Save() {
    $("#NAME").attr("action", $('.save').attr("href"));
    $("#NAME").submit();
     });
</script>
```

In my Controller class i wrote method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "href_form1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String href_form1(UserForm userForm,Model model)throws Exception {
    //Database code here.       
    model.addAttribute("NAME", userForm);
    return "User Updated";
}
```

**EDIT1:**

```
WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

and i'm getting error page.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
```

**EDIT:** after modify the code like below

```
   <script>
  $(function() {
   $('.save').on("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#NAME").attr("action", $(this).attr("href")).attr("method","POST");
     $("#NAME").submit();
   });
  });
</script>
```

But my form will not reach the my controller method.

Is there anything wrong in my code? I've also tried `method="POST"` in the form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reason you are getting the error

The link's href is calling the controller when clicked because you do not cancel the default action of the link

So the code does the following

1. attempts to set the action of a form to the href of the link
2. attempts to submit said form using POST - this is what I understand you want to achieve.
3. regardless of whether or not this succeeds, the browser immediately follows the href of the link which will try to call the controller with a GET as a link will do if the onclick does not stop that action. Even if the code succeeded in POSTing the form, that request will be killed by the new request which ends up doing a GET

In my opinion you have the following possibilities - some of them are supposedly better practice than others.

**Non-javascript**

1. Have a parameter that holds the identification of what you want to save - and a form per parameter
2. change your spring method to
   `method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}` or
   `method = RequestMethod.GET` - the GET will allow you to get rid of the form and just have the following link (after updating the spring code of course)

```
 <a href="href_link?user=user1">Save User1</a>
```

if you so wish

**JavaScript assisted**

Have a parameter in the form that holds the identification of what you want to save, set THAT by JavaScript and perform a **MANDATORY** `return false` or `preventDefault`  to cancel the link:

```
<!-- this is an example of the rendered form -->
<form action="href_form1" id="NAME" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="saveItem" id="saveItem" value="" />
</form>  

<a href="#" class="saveLink" data-save="save item 1">Save item 1</a>
<a href="#" class="saveLink" data-save="save item 2">Save item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="saveLink" data-save="save item 3">Save item 3</a>
```

Please note I do not have a link in the href to avoid requesting something

The jQuery to go with this process:

```
$(function() {
  // assuming form ID="NAME"
  $(".saveLink").on("click",function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault(); // do not follow link
     $("#saveItem").val($(this).data("save")); // set the hidden field
     $("#NAME").submit();
  });
});
```

---

Here is a perhaps more interesting way for you, assuming your spring controllers are hooked up to handle your requests:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ptDXy/)

```
  $(function() {
   $('.save').on("click",function(e) { // passing event
     e.preventDefault(); // jQuery will normalise it for all modern browsers
     // post the href of the link to the server and return the result in a 
     // container with ID result
     $.post($(this).attr("href"), function(data) { // or $.get if you want
       $('#result').html(data);
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `method` in the `form` tag. And yes, your hyperlink is ignoring the form. So set the `action` attribute on the form to `href_form1` and change your hyperlink to a submit input or (and I wouldn't really recommend this) change your hyperlink to do a JavaScript submission. At the moment, you have `onclick` *and* `href` setup in the link. Below is best practise.

```
<form:form action="href_form1" modelAttribute="NAME" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Also your jQuery selector `$("#NAME")` isn't finding anything because you haven't set the `id` attribute on the form you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this

```
<form:form action="href_form1" modelAttribute="NAME" method="POST">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form:form>

@RequestMapping(value = "href_form1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String href_form1(UserForm userForm,Model model)throws Exception {
    //Database code here.       
    model.addAttribute("NAME", userForm);
    return "User Updated";
}
```

Basically a very simple form submit. Once you get this working, you know that your form and controller are properly setup. After this if you want to use a anchor tag to submit the form, go back to earlier suggestions, `preventDefault` and then form submit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Default http method for form submission is GET. Since you want POST please specify that and it will work liek `method="POST"`

Also I do not see the url mapping correctly in the code. Could you please confirm if its correct.

Comment: Even after adding `method="POST"` it was just because he had an `href` attribute set that was being followed instead of ignored. That and the `action` attribute wasn't getting changed because the JavaScript wasn't referencing the form correctly as it didn't have an `id` attribute.